# Don't scroll the diff buttons on the review window

Tags: feature-request, edits, design

When reviewing an edit of a large post the diff buttons on the left will get scrolled out of the viewpane when scolling down.

Would it be possible to keep those in the same spot even when scrolling?

[image]

A quick fix would be something like:

```
/* Added position: absolute; */
.answer-summary .statscontainer { width: 40px; position: absolute; }

/* Added margin-left: 47px; */
.suggested-edit .summary { width: 910px; margin-left: 47px; }
```

This is just a quick fix without checking other browsers than Chrome, but it wouldn't surprise me if `position: relative;` also has to be added for IE on `.popup .question-summary`.

Not a bug improvement, but it is nice to not have to scroll all the way back to the top to change the diff output.